# Почему программа крашится неким WerFault.exe?

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
У меня есть программа которая захватывает нажатые клавиши с клавиатуры на низком уровне и сохраняет клавиши в файл.
Но есть проблема. При запуске, когда программа начинает записывать клавишу в файл - она тупо крашится процессом WerFault.exe (узнал с помощью ProcessHacker). Кто нибудь может помочь? Скоре всего крашится именно на моменте `File.WriteAllText()`, ибо когда я его убрал - всё было нормально.
Полный код: https://pastebin.com/CN92FMuN

Comment: [The werfault.exe is used for Windows Error Reporting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4032dc41-c813-4058-bba2-27317b38bf63/werfaultexe?forum=w8itproappcompat)

Comment: добавьте [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) для воспроизведения в вопрос

Comment: возможно пытаетесь писать в несколько потоков. Попробыйте использовать lock

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev , можно поподробней про lock?

Comment: @SharpPythoneist  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev , и куда мне его вставлять? Не совсем понял...